# Conditions in T-SQL Query

Tags: sql-server

A table named `Fruit` has columns `ID`, `Fruit name` and `Cost` and `New Cost`:

```
  |ID | Fruit Name | Cost | New Cost
  +---+------------+------+---------
  | 1 | Apple      |  10  |    9 
  | 2 | Banana     |  20  |   22
  | 3 | Orange     |  33  |   33
```

I wish to query this table under one condition. If New Cost is more than Cost then Final Cost should be 0.9*Cost else Final Cost should be New Cost.

Output should look like:

```
  | ID | Fruit Name | Final Cost 
  +----+------------+-----------
  | 1  | Apple      |    9  
  | 2  | Banana     |   18    
  | 3  | Orange     |   29.7
```

Unfortunately, I am not able to apply If condition in SQL query. Is there any way to achieve this??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use CASE LOGIC to arrive at the resultset.

```sql
SELECT ID
, FruitName
, CASE WHEN [New Cost] > [Cost] THEN 0.9 * [Cost] 
       ELSE [New Cost] 
       END AS [Final Cost]
FROM 
Fruit
```

Answer (score 0):

Please check this answer

```
DECLARE @table TABLE
(
    ID INT IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEy,
    FruteName NVARCHAR(200),
    Cost DECIMAL(10,2),
    NewCost DECIMAL(10,2)
)

INSERT INTO @table VALUES('Apple','10',9),('Banana','20',22),('Orange','33',33)

SELECT *, IIF(NewCost>=Cost,(Cost*0.9),NewCost) AS FinalCost
FROM @table
```

[image]